# Send mail from powershell as anonymous user

Tags: email, powershell, powershell-3.0

I've always used the cmdlet `Send-MailMessage` without specifying any `-Credential`. Now I need to send mail using the anonymous user. The workaround I've found is this piece of code

```
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "anyString"-AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON",$pass
Send-MailMessage -Credential $cred #...
```

It works, but is this the correct method to get the anonymous is and send anonymous mail?

Comment: If the mail server will do anonymous relay, you shouldn't need to sepcify credentials at all.

Comment: I guess the mail server doesn't do anonymous relay. In our infrastructure only users with mailbox can sand mail to mail server, but I'm using an administrator with elevated credential (and without mailbox), and mail server won't accept mail from that user. Do you think it makes sense or mail server isn't configured properly? Given that I can't modify this mail server neither ask for any change, is there a 'clean' way to send mail as anonymous user?

Comment: Is this an Exchange transport server?

Comment: Good! Are you running the script on the Exchange server?

Comment: no, it's from a remote server

Answer (score 2):

You can send mail from any address, it just depends on whether the receiving mail server cares about whether it can verify the sending user or not.

For example if you send from `anon@microsoft.com` and microsoft does not have that account, OR they have SPF records to indicate whether the sending mail server is valid or not, then the receiving mail server **might**(not always) reject it.

Just make sure your email user actually exists and has a valid domain... and you can send from anonymous@ or noreply@ or whatever you want to.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm using an administrative user without mailbox, and mail server won't accept mail only from this user. The mail server administrator said that I need to send mail as anonymous user

Answer (score 1):

Okay, from the comments we know we're dealing with an Exchange server. Whether or not it will do an anonymous relay depends on the configuration of the Recieve Connectors.  But those restrictions only apply to the network connections.  If you run Send-MailMessage on the Exchange server and use 'LocalHost' as your SMTPServer it didn't go through a receive connector so those restrictions don't apply.

If you have remoting enabled on the Exchange server you can use that to do a local invocation to send email without having to modify the Receive Connector configurations:

```
$EmailParams =
    @{
      To         = '<Email To>'
      From       = '<Email From>'
      Subject    = '<Email Subject>'
      Body       = '<Email Body>'
      SMTPServer = 'localhost'
     }

  $Scriptblock = [Scriptblock]::Create(
   "Send-MailMessage $(&{$args} @EmailParams) ")
 Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ComputerName ExchangeServer
```

Comment: thank you for the proposed solution but I can't connect remotely via powershell this way

Comment: If your Exchange administrator wants you to use anonymous relay, then he's going to have to configure one of his receive connectors to do it.